# How to load IPython shell with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython, pyspark

I want to load IPython shell (not IPython notebook) in which I can use PySpark through command line. Is that possible?
I have installed Spark-1.4.1.

Comment: You might want to try [findspark](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/findspark).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you use Spark < 1.2 you can simply execute `bin/pyspark` with an environmental variable `IPYTHON=1`.

```
IPYTHON=1 /path/to/bin/pyspark
```

or

```
export IPYTHON=1
/path/to/bin/pyspark
```

While above will still work on the Spark 1.2 and above recommended way to set Python environment for these versions is `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON`

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython /path/to/bin/pyspark
```

or

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython
/path/to/bin/pyspark
```

You can replace `ipython` with a path to the interpreter of your choice.

Comment: Thanks. That was magic. But I am getting this error when I tried defining sparkContext: `Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=PySparkShell, master=local[*]) created by <module> at /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py:116`

Comment: Also, how can I run it with specific version of python? it is currently running it with python3.4 but i want to run it with python2.7. I am asking because I am getting this error: `Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.4, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions`

Comment: That's a different story. `pyspark` shell (same as `spark-shell` and  `sparkR`) creates `SparkContext` and `SQLContext` instances on start. You can access these using `sc` and `sqlContext` respectively. Since Spark allows only one context per JVM you have to stop existing one before you can create a new one with specific options. To do that you can simply call `sc.stop()`. To choose a specific version of Python interpreter you can use `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON`.

Comment: I've just read that `IPYTHON` variable is depreciated and you should simply use `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython`. So you can simply replace `ipython` with a path to the desired version.

Comment: Any idea where can i find path for different ipython versions?

Comment: What OS do you use? Do you have working IPython + Python 2.7 installation? How do you start it?

Comment: I am on MACOSX. I just type ipython2 for 2.7 and ipython3 for 3.4

Comment: In that case you can simply try `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython2`

Comment: This seems to cause a problem in late model pyspark that I've never seen before:   

`/Users/rjurney/Software/anaconda3/bin/pyspark: line 24: /Users/rjurney/Software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
/Users/rjurney/Software/anaconda3/bin/pyspark: line 77: /Users/rjurney/Software/my.project//Users/rjurney/Software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 13):

This answer is an adapted and shortened version of a [similar post my website](https://jupyter.ai/pyspark-session/): https://jupyter.ai/pyspark-session/

I use **ptpython(1)**, which supplies **ipython** functionality as well as your choice of either **vi(1)** or **emacs(1)** key-bindings. It also supplies dynamic code pop-up/intelligence, which is extremely useful when performing ad-hoc SPARK work on the CLI, or simply trying to learn the Spark API.

Here is what my **vi**-enabled **ptpython** session looks like, taking note of the **VI (INSERT)** mode at the bottom of the screehshot, as well as the **ipython** style prompt to indicate that those **ptpython** capabilities have been selected (more on how to select them in a moment):

[image]

**To get all of this, perform the following simple steps**:

```
user@linux$ pip3 install ptpython # Everything here assumes Python3

user@linux$ vi ${SPARK_HOME}/conf/spark-env.sh
    # Comment-out/disable the following two lines. This is necessary because
    # they take precedence over any UNIX environment settings for them:
       # PYSPARK_PYTHON=/path/to/python
       # PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/path/to/python

user@linux$ vi ${HOME}/.profile # Or whatever your login RC-file is.
    # Add these two lines:
       export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3           # Fully-Qualify this if necessary. (python3)
       export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ptpython3  # Fully-Qualify this if necessary. (ptpython3)

user@linux$ . ${HOME}/.profile  # Source the RC file.

user@linux$ pyspark
    # You are now running pyspark(1) within ptpython; a code pop-up/interactive
    # shell; with your choice of vi(1) or emacs(1) key-bindings; and 
    # your choice of ipython functionality or not.
```

To select your **pypython** preferences (and there are a bunch of them), simply press **F2** from within a **ptpython** session, and select whatever options you want.

**CLOSING NOTE**: If you are submitting a Python Spark Application (as opposed to interacting with pyspark(1) via the CLI, as shown above), simply set **PYSPARK_PYTHON** and **PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON** programmatically in Python, like so:

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = 'python3'
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = 'python3' # Not 'ptpython3' in this case.
```

I hope this answer and setup is useful.

Answer (score 7):

if version of spark >= 2.0 and the follow config could be adding to .bashrc

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/data/venv/your_env/bin/python
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/data/venv/your_env/bin/ipython
```

Answer (score 6):

Tested with spark 3.0.1 and python 3.7.7 (with ipython/jupyter installed)

To start pyspark with IPython:

`$ PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark`

To start pyspark with jupyter notebook:

`$ PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook pyspark`

Answer (score 5):

According to the official Github, IPYTHON=1 is not available in Spark 2.0+
Please use PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON instead.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/pyspark

Answer (score 4):

Here is what worked for me:

```
# if you run your ipython with 2.7 version with ipython2
# whatever you use for launching ipython shell should come after '=' sign
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython2
```

and then from the SPARK_HOME directory:

```
./bin/pyspark
```

Answer (score 4):

What I found to be helpful is to write bash scripts that load Spark in a specific way. Doing this will give you an easy way to start Spark in different environments (for example ipython and a jupyter notebook).

To do this open a blank script (using whatever text editor you prefer), for example one called `ipython_spark.sh`

For this example I will provide the script I use to open spark with the ipython interpreter:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython

${SPARK_HOME}/bin/pyspark \
--master local[4] \
--executor-memory 1G \
--driver-memory 1G \
--conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir="file:///tmp/spark-warehouse" \
--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0 \
--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.34 \
--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3
```

Note that I have SPARK_HOME defined in my bash_profile, but you could just insert the whole path to wherever pyspark is located on your computer

I like to put all scripts like this in one place so I put this file in a folder called "scripts"

Now for this example you need to go to your bash_profile and enter the following lines:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<username>/scripts
alias ispark="bash /Users/<username>/scripts/ipython_spark.sh"
```

These paths will be specific to where you put ipython_spark.sh
and then you might need to update permissions:

```
$ chmod 711 ipython_spark.sh
```

and source your bash_profile:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

I'm on a mac, but this should all work for linux as well, although you will be updating .bashrc instead of bash_profile most likely.

What I like about this method is that you can write up multiple scripts, with different configurations and open spark accordingly. Depending on if you are setting up a cluster, need to load different packages, or change the number of cores spark has at it's disposal, etc. you can either update this script, or make new ones. As noted by @zero323 above PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON= is the correct syntax for Spark > 1.2
I am using Spark 2.2

Answer (score 4):

None of the mentioned answers worked for me. I always got the error:

```
.../pyspark/bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
```

What I did was launching `ipython` and creating Spark session manually:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("example-spark")\
    .config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled","true")\
    .getOrCreate()
```

To avoid doing this every time, I moved the code to `~/.ispark.py` and created the following alias (add this to `~/.bashrc`):

```
alias ipyspark="ipython -i ~/.ispark.py"
```

After that, you can launch PySpark with iPython by typing:

```
ipyspark
```

Comment: this worked for me, running a docker image of amazonlinux

Comment: For the ".../load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory" error, I just figured out the root cause and made a fix: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/28256

Comment: Update: the ".../load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory" error was fixed by https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/28957/ spark 3.0 should work.