# Submitting Python Application with Apache Spark Submit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to follow the examples on the Apache Spark documentation site: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/submitting-applications.html

I started a Spark standalone cluster and want to run the example Python application. I am in my spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7 directory and ran the following command

```
./bin/spark-submit \
--master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 \
examples/src/main/python/pi.py \
1000
```

However, I get the error

```
jupyter: '/Users/MyName/spark-2.0.0-bin- \
hadoop2.7/examples/src/main/python/pi.py' is not a Jupyter command
```

This is what my bash_profile looks like

```
#setting path for Spark
export SPARK_PATH=~/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
alias snotebook='$SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --master local[2]'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unset `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS` before submitting.

Answer (score 1):

The `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS` are meant for running the ipython/jupyter shell when opening the pyspark shell ( More info at [How to load IPython shell with PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862293/how-to-load-ipython-shell-with-pyspark) ).

You can set this up like:

```
alias snotebook='PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook $SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --master local[2]'
```

So that it doesn't interfere with pyspark when submitting

Answer (score 1):

Add `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython` before the spark-submit command.

Example:

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython ./bin/spark-submit \ 
/home/SimpleApp.py
```

Comment: Nice. Only problem is if I want to pass arguments to the python script. For some reason Ipython is interferring, thinking they are for it.