# jupyter notebook interferes with spark submit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I installed Spark with Hadoop pre-built on my OS X and integrated PySpark with Jupyter Notebook. Basically I type "pyspark" in my terminal Jupyter Notebook pops up. Everything works fine.

But when I used spark-sumit with the following command:

```
spark-submit --master local[*] --total-executor-cores 1 --driver-memory 2g server.py
```

I got an error:

```
jupyter: '/Users/XXX/some_path/server.py' is not a Jupyter command
```

Seems Jupyter interferes with spark-sumit. Here's my bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/Users/XXX/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/XXX/Spark/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.6/bin:$PATH"
export SPARK_HOME="/Users/XXX/Spark/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.6"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/Users/XXX/anaconda/bin/python2.7
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/Users/XXX/anaconda/bin/jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

I know that this must be the problem of my environment variables. When I delete the last two lines it works. I followed the answer to this question [Submitting Python Application with Apache Spark Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302113/submitting-python-application-with-apache-spark-submit), none of them worked in my case. Also someone said unset `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS` before submitting would work.

Is there a better way to set my environment variables such that I can use Jupyer Notebook when I type `pyspark` and I can also use `spark-submit`?

Any ideas would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can create script with content:

```
$!/usr/bin/bash
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/Users/XXX/anaconda/bin/jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
exec pyspark
```

And name it `pyspark-jupyter`, place somewhere inside your bash's `$PATH` and it should work as you expect.

Comment: If so should I delete `export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/Users/XXX/anaconda/bin/jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'` in my bash_profile?

Comment: Yes, they are needed only during jupyter initilization.