# How do I launch pyspark and arrive in an ipython shell

Tags: bash, pyspark

When I launch pyspark, spark loads properly, however I end up in a standard python shell environment.

```
Using Python version 2.7.13 (default, Dec 20 2016 23:05:08)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>>
```

I want to launch into the ipython interpreter.

```
IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
In [1]:
```

How do I do that? I tried modifying my .bashprofile in this way and using the alias:

```
# Spark variables
export SPARK_HOME="/Users/micahshanks/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7"
export PYTHONPATH="/Users/micahshanks/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/:"

# Spark 2
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
# export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH

alias sudo='sudo '
alias pyspark="/Users/micahshanks/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark \
--conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir='file:///tmp/spark-warehouse' \
--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0 \
--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.34 \
--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 \
--packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.10:2.0.0"
```

I also tried navigating to spark home where pyspark is located and directly launching from there, but again I arrive in the python interpreter.

I found this post: [How to load IPython shell with PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862293/how-to-load-ipython-shell-with-pyspark) and the accepted answer looked promising, but am activating python 2 environment (source activate py2) before launching spark and changing my bash profile in this way attempts to start spark with python 3 which I'm not setup to do (throws errors).

I'm using spark 2.1

Comment: PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython and then ./bin/pyspark to load ipython works for me. Normally you type ipython to load ipython but for pyspark you need to type ./bin/pyspark

Comment: @GlenThompson unfortunately that doesn't work for me. When I open spark from my terminal after navigating to the bin folder: `.\bin\pyspark` it opens in the regular python interpreter. I actually have to use `sudo pyspark` or else spark does not open and I receive this error along with many other warnings: `ERROR 25505: A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection`, but either way not the outcome I am looking for as I want to open in the ipython interpreter

Comment: First I wouldn't navigate to the bin folder, just in the root folder of the spark download, after you decompress the download type `export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython` then `./bin/pyspark` however when I type `sudo ./bin/pyspark` I get the error you see and its all jacked up. Now you broke mine :P Last time I fixed it by just deleting the entire directory and decompressing again, following the commands above. sudo messes something up.. Sorry thats not more helpful, maybe someone knows why...

Comment: @GlenThompson that worked! i'll have to dig in to the bash scripts to figure out why. note that I had to add all the configuration and package arguments after ./bin/pyspark, but then my python script executed. If you want to add a formal answer I will accept it and if I figure out a bit more about why exactly it works I'll post it here

Comment: Actually the following works without having to re-download and decompress `sudo chown -v $(id -un) metastore_db/db.lck` `sudo ./bin/pyspark` changes the db.lck file permissions which effects things somehow.

Comment: I did not have to use sudo when opening by ./bin/pyspark, only after entering the bin directory and attempting to open pyspark. Permissions in on folder fine, permissions in the other not...but thanks for the tip

Comment: Yeh you shouldn't use sudo it messes with the permissions so that when you don't use sudo you have user issues, either way can you upvote my answer if it was satisfactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Spark 2.1.1**

For some reason typing `sudo ./bin/pyspark` changes the file permissions of `metastore_db/db.lck` that cause running ipython and pyspark not to work. From the decompressed root directory try:

`sudo chown -v $(id -un) metastore_db/db.lck`

`export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython`

`./bin/pyspark`

Another solution is to just re-download and decompress from [spark.apache.org](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html). Navigate to the root of the decompressed directory and then:

`export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython`

`./bin/pyspark`

And it should work.

Comment: I tried loading pyspark in Ipython for like 2 days and finally got this super easy answer, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Since asking this question I found a helpful solution is to write bash scripts that load Spark in a specific way. Doing this will give you an easy way to start Spark in different environments (for example ipython and a jupyter notebook).

To do this open a blank script (using whatever text editor you prefer), for example one called `ipython_spark.sh`

For this example I will provide the script I use to open spark with the ipython interpreter:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython

${SPARK_HOME}/bin/pyspark \
--master local[4] \
--executor-memory 1G \
--driver-memory 1G \
--conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir="file:///tmp/spark-warehouse" \
--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0 \
--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.34 \
--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3
```

Note that I have SPARK_HOME defined in my bash_profile, but you could just insert the whole path to wherever pyspark is located on your computer

I like to put all scripts like this in one place so I put this file in a folder called "scripts"

Now for this example you need to go to your bash_profile and enter the following lines:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<username>/scripts
alias ispark="bash /Users/<username>/scripts/ipython_spark.sh"
```

These paths will be specific to where you put ipython_spark.sh
and then you might need to update permissions:

```
$ chmod 711 ipython_spark.sh
```

and source your bash_profile:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

I'm on a mac, but this should all work for linux as well, although you will be updating .bashrc instead of bash_profile most likely.

What I like about this method is that you can write up multiple scripts, with different configurations and open spark accordingly. Depending on if you are setting up a cluster, need to load different packages, or change the number of cores spark has at it's disposal, etc. you can either update this script, or make new ones. Note that PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON= is the correct syntax for Spark > 1.2
I am using Spark 2.2